# How do I assign a value to the Path key in a .desktop file including the $HOME environment variable correctly?

Tags: freedesktop, .desktop, assignment

I'm making a .desktop file for Minecraft. Nothing appears to happen upon executing the it. The Exec and Path keys in the file:

```
Exec=java -jar Minecraft.jar
Path=$HOME/.minecraft/
```

I've also tried using a `~` instead of `$HOME`. Freedesktop's [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) doesn't mention any strict rules for the Path key, but it does for the [Exec key](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables), and I've tried applying it's rules in the Path key too.

I have found a workaround for making my .desktop file through [a previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175123/how-do-i-write-a-command-for-the-exec-key-in-a-desktop-file-containing-a-reserv), but I would still like to know how to make it work with the Path key.

Comment: As I said in my comment to your other question you have to provide absolute paths. `$HOME` is not expanded in a desktop file (if it's part of an argument passed to `sh` command then the shell will expand it).